# is it necessary to format windows XP OS to do partitioning for Ubuntu, and how do I do it properly to then install Ubuntu from disk

Tags: windows, windows-xp, format

is it necessary to format windows XP OS to do partitioning for Ubuntu, and how do I do it properly to then install Ubuntu 10.10 from disk, and would it work from 10.10 to get 12.04 updates?

Thank you all; for being, for being soooo forth-giving and for all you ever will to be. I endeavor to support and be of such torch-carrying also, and Am honored by the beautious examples of the people in these forums.

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? No, you don't have to remove Windows XP. Yes, if you don't have unpartitioned space for Ubuntu, you'll have to resize other partitions.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not necessary. The current Ubuntu installer offers you automatically to shrink the windows partition on your hard drive and install Ubuntu to the remaining space. Just select "Install Ubuntu along with Windows" when you come to the Question about partitioning.

If you feel like it make a backup of your windows data before tinkering with partitioning. But generally tho process is save nowadays.